# How to pass data from view controller to first tab of tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I want to pass image and news from view controller to connected first tab of tabbar controller .The first tab the NewsViewController is not displaying the news title and image. didSelectRowAt indexPath method as follow.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let storybaord=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBar=storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController
    let DVC = tabBar.viewControllers?[0] as! NewsViewController
    tabBar.selectedIndex = 0
    DVC.getImage=sneakersnews[indexPath.row].image
    DVC.getNews=sneakersnews[indexPath.row].news
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)
}
```

How to pass and display the news and image on first tab NewsViewController from the table view?

**You can download the project from this link:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qfI3UaXoUTzOS6Jfe40wj99NAifVkz5Y/view?usp=sharing**

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: first tab(NewsViewController) of tab bar controller is not displaying image and news title on the view controller.

Comment: Try Using Segue .

Comment: Your tabbar is nil in your project

Comment: Add a check in viewDidLoad it will solve your problem.

Comment: How to pass and display the news and image on first tab NewsViewController ?

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you are doing two different things

1. there is a segue between DiscoveryNewsViewController and tabbarController
2. You are pushing tabbar controller like this

   ```
   let DVC = tabBar.viewControllers?[0] as! NewsViewController
   //this is not required as it will always open UIViewController at Zero index so comment this
   //tabBar.selectedIndex = 0
   let image = sneakersnews[indexPath.row].image
   DVC.getImage = image
   let news = sneakersnews[indexPath.row].news
   DVC.getNews = news
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)
   ```

Please read commented lines in above code

So you cannot do both above mention points at a time because a segue connection is already pushing your TabBarController and your self.navigationController?.pushViewController is also pushing TabBarController.

SOLUTION:-

1. Just embed DiscoveryNewsViewController in navigation controller

2.Remove segue connection between  DiscoveryNewsViewController and tabbarController

[image]

Comment: I have table view controller in side tabbar controller .The problem is when i click when i select a row in table view it does not loads the second tab bar controller from the existing tab bar controller ...You can download this code from this link .https://drive.google.com/file/d/10w9MQaRxGlMSG_lK07N1c7nJWQLC8BWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ajadka  I think i have answer your question.This is not good that when you accept anybody's answer then mark it  as unaccepted because now your requirement is changed.You should ask it as another question.

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldnt push a tabbar into navigation controller. So, remove the segue in storyboard between DiscoveryNewsViewController and TabBar

so replace

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)
```

with

```
self.present(tabBar, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

2. Since you are not refreshing your assigned value to image and label in UI so its not displaying. To do that just create a function

   func refreshData() 
   {
       newsTitle.text = getNews
       NewsImage.image = getImage
   }

in NewsViewController
and call it just after

```
DVC.getImage=sneakersnews[indexPath.row].image
DVC.getNews=sneakersnews[indexPath.row].news
```

like this

```
DVC.refreshData()
```

Comment: @ navneet Why he cannot push?

Comment: I am not using this statement in my code self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)    ..... Instead i am using these two statement in didSelectRowAt indexPath .....let storybaord=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBar=storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController

Comment: @user511 because it's not recommended by apple itself... It may cause strange behaviours

Comment: Basically you are pushing tabbar through segue and also creating a new tabbar instance in didselectrow method... You need to fix which one you want to use

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code, and get the problem and many test!

Not a complex problem but need take care next time.

It's because you connect a segue from your cell to a TabbarController, and when you tab the cell, it will automatic goto the tabbarController due to the segue.

and you init another tabbarController and pass the data then present it. you make a breakpoint in your NewsViewController viewDidLoad and can see hit twice.

There are many other problems in your code,
In my opinion, you can only use the segue to pass data, To make your code stable and predictable